# Postgresql too many clients already error

Tags: postgresql

I have a server running on windows server 2012 VM with 4GB of memory.

this machine runs a postgresql server with 'max_connections' = 100

However, when I run my **4th** client and try to connect to postgres i get 
"**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already**"

Any suggestions?

Comment: it's highly likely that you are not closing connections to the database, you can check [`pg_stat_activity`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html) view it will give you more info.

Comment: thank you.
By viewing the statistics I noticed that each one of my clients opens about 10 connections.